# TFS to Marklogic Integration for deployment

Tags: xquery, marklogic

Does anyone know about any type plugin or tool through which we can do integration of TFS with MarkLogic which can help us doing deployment directly from TFS to MarkLogic Module database.

Comment: Can you define a service end point for use to deploy modules via REST? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/library/service-endpoints?view=vsts

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for your reply. Is there any rest end point available which can can expose the files stored in TFS.

Comment: Yes.  https://www.nwcadence.com/blog/vststfs-rest-api-the-basics-and-working-with-builds-and-releases talks about some of the rest endpoints, and should point you in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

You will need a TFS client to first fetch the files from TFS, and then load the modules into MarkLogic.

It's the same sort of process that you would have for any version control system, such as Git or SVN. You need to obtain the modules from the version control repository and then deploy them.

For instance, for a CI environment you can configure a Jenkins project to use the [TFS Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Team+Foundation+Server+Plugin) to poll and look for changes or build periodically on a schedule, and then use your build/deployment scripts, such as [ml-gradle](https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle) build to deploy to MarkLogic with the appropriate target (i.e. mlRedeploy, mlReloadModules, etc) depending upon whether it is a complete install or re-install, or if you simply want incremental deployment of module changes.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no tool/functionality available.